# Oracle: Opening the same cursor within different IF statements

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to open a cursor within an `IF` statement block like so:

```
PROCEDURE CURSORIFSTATEMENT (param IN INT, iocursor IN OUT t_cursor)
IS
  v_cursor t_cursor;
BEGIN
  IF param = 1 THEN
    OPEN v_cursor FOR

    SELECT a.field
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.fieldid = a fieldid;

    io_cursor := v_cursor;
    CLOSE v_cursor;
  ELSIF param = 2 THEN
    OPEN v_cursor FOR

    SELECT a.field, c.field
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.fieldid = a.fieldid
    INNER JOIN table3 c ON c.fieldid = a.fieldid;

    io_cursor := v_cursor;
    CLOSE v_cursor;
  END IF;
END CURSORIFSTATEMENT;
```

So basically, the goal would be to fill the cursor depending on which `IF` statement is true.

Comment: Yes, But only if it is `REFCURSOR`..

Comment: `io_cursor := v_cursor; CLOSE v_cursor;` Maybe this is a stupid question, but you close the cursor you will return?

Comment: +1 @MaheswaranRavisankar. Just declare a `REF CURSOR` and use it in the `IF-ELSE` construct. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue with your requirement and your attempt. Since, `IF-ELSE` condition is not allowed in cursor, however, in `PL/SQL`, using a `REF CURSOR` you could do :

```
DECLARE 
  CUR REF CURSOR ;
    BEGIN 
       IF (so and so) THEN 
         OPEN CUR IS 'SELECT * FROM table_1'; 
       ELSE (so and so)
         OPEN CUR IS 'SELECT * FORM table_2';
     END IF ;
END;
```